# Email verification not coming

Tags: icloud, accounts

I have signed up with a .edu.pk domain and waiting for email verification, but it's been hours since I haven't gotten it. Is there any issue with .edu.pk and apple?

Comment: Can you log in via the [iCloud.com](http://icloud.com) website?

Comment: @Lukas no, it says you have to login using OSX or iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

Apple have no special conditions for .edu.pk, so it should work. Try the usual suspects:

- Check your spam folder
- Check your email rules
- Check your mail server isn't rejecting the email

If all else fails, try resetting your password at [iforgot.apple.com](http://iforgot.apple.com/).